# SIM-Application access via iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to create a shortcut to a SIM-Application. So is it somehow possible to access a SIM-App via iOS App? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access the SIM card from iOS with public APIs.

You can search for private headers to use in your project, but you won't get approved for release on the AppStore.